# argument problem On function argument ($0,$1);+jquery,js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, arguments

Doubt On function($0,$1);
 // $0,$1  two argument
**My question is this two argument are Not defined But it hold some data on it ???**

can any on help to Understand
how this two argument run;

```
function strip_tags(input, allowed) {
    allowed = (((allowed || "") + "").toLowerCase().match(/<[a-z][a-z0-9]*>/g) || []).join(''); 
   //console.log('----------->'+allowed.join('ss'));
    var tags = /<\/?([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>/gi,
        commentsAndPhpTags = /<!--[\s\S]*?-->|<\?(?:php)?[\s\S]*?\?>/gi;
    return input.replace(commentsAndPhpTags,'').replace(tags, function ($0, $1) { // need help to understand $0 , $1
      //console.log('----------->'+$1);
        return allowed.indexOf('<' + $1.toLowerCase() + '>') > -1 ? $0 : '';
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you referring to the fact that JavaScript functions form [lexical closures][1] or that $0 and $1 were somehow bound to something you didn't expect? Could you please clarify your question please?


  [1]: http://mark-story.com/posts/view/picking-up-javascript-closures-and-lexical-scoping

Comment: If your client side `strip_tags` function is your only security precaution, you're doomed. If you have a strip-tags function on the server side, you can throw that one away.

Answer (score 1):

That is a really bad way to sanitize markup. It's almost guaranteed to have some loopholes. A simpler way would just be to strip all markup:

```
var stripTags = function(str) {
  return str.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, '');
};
```

As far as allowing specific elements goes, it would be better to write a tokenizer, iterate over the tokens, drop everything that's not allowed, and then output the markup from those tokens.

But if you don't care to write a tokenizer, this would be a better way of going about it, even though it's still kind of crude:

```
var allowed = { p: true, a: true };
var sanitize = function(str) {
  return str.replace(/<\s*\/?\s*([^\s>]+)[^>]*>/g, function(tag, name) {
    if (!allowed[name.toLowerCase()]) {
      return '';
    }
    return tag;
  });
};
```

But as the comment above mentions, if you're only sanitizing a user's markup on the client-side, it's a **major** problem. You need to be doing sanitization on the server-side.

Comment: +1 for taking the time. There are many things in the code the wrong way I din't feel like correcting everything. @k6t back: Make the right decision, drop your code and go with this one, for client side validation only.

Answer (score 0):

```
return input.replace(commentsAndPhpTags, '').replace(tags, function (input, group1) {
    //console.log('----------->'+group1);
    return allowed.indexOf('<' + group1.toLowerCase() + '>') > -1 ? input : '';
});
```

You regex `/<\/?([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>/gi` contains only a group match, which will be the content inside parentheses `([a-z][a-z0-9]*)`, `replace()` will pass to your function the original string and the group matches.

**However**, your regex should be like this `/(<\/?[a-z][a-z0-9]*\b[^>]*>)/gi` in order to be able to strip the tags.